# How to change authentcated users to the Google Drive API

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have followed [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) tutorial to fetch the drive name list from the Google Drive.

This code is working fine. however, I want to know if I can force the authentication again (something like log out, but I think google isn't call it like that).

Currently I need to wait the consent to time out in order to select another account.

(If I start the application first time or the previous session has timed out, a Google consent page will be prompted so that I can select or add a particular account to authenticate).

I am using OAuth2 and the platform is .NET window form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you post all of your code wrather then just linking a tutorial you followed.

The way the Google API dotnet client library works is that it stores the user credentials in a datastore on your machine.   In the following section of code  "user" denotes a users credentials if you change that you can force it to swap between users.   If a user does not have credentials then it will pop up and ask you for authentication again.  To fully understand how filedata store works I recommend you read my tutorial on the subject [Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

In the world of Oauth there really is no such thing as logging out.  Technically speaking you have access to a users data until they remove that access or something happens to your refresh token.    It will be up to you to change the "user" in your code to make it appear that the user has logged out on your site.   The only thing that is close to this is [Revoking](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) the token which is basically removing your access to a users data.  the user will have to authenticate your application again if they chose to login again.

Comment: the reason that i didn't copy the code is just because it is really just the same as the link provided... do you mean if I changed the string "user" to dynamic timestamp which will be defined during login of my system. it will do the trick so that the reauthentication will be done again after user logged in or out again? thanks

Comment: yes technically it would. but you are going to end up with a lot of datastores on your machine.  and there is still the potential of more then one user.

Comment: i really can achieve re-authenticate by using timestamp method during login/logout. however, you hgave showed your concern, do you have better solution for that? ( i think most people using this API actually really need a handy way to achieve re-authentication, and surprisingly there is not much article talk about that )

Comment: link the users login on your website their google credentials is an idea.  I think that requesting a users authentication every time they visit your site is really going to annoy your users.

Comment: thanks. any article talks about the implementation of your first sentence (link the users login on your website their google credentials is an idea)? i will do further study on it as i'm agree your second sentence (as it annoy me when i doing testing)

Comment: one of the official samples might give you some ideas there is an asp.net one and a couple of mvc samples they are not very up to date https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples